# Finding Laurent series of a function $f(z)=\frac{3z^2-6z+1}{(z-1)(3z-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How do i transform this function into Laurent series
$$f(z)=\frac{3z^2-6z+1}{(z-1)(3z-1)}$$
where $ \frac{1}{3} < |z| < 1 $.

Comment: Could you show your work, and tell us where you're having problems, so we know where to focus our efforts on?

Comment: I don't even know where to start, because in our lectures we only did a couple of trivial examples.

Comment: Hint:Partial fraction.

Comment: Laurent series around which pole? $\frac13$ or $1$ ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli neither of them, clearly his asking for the Laurent series on the annulus $\{ z : 1/3<|z|<1\}$, hence the Laurent series is around $z=0$. Note that this makes sense since the annular region does not contain any pole

Comment: Sorry, @AlonsoDelfín my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT** Since $|z|<1$, then 
$$
\frac{1}{z-1} =-\frac{1}{1-z}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n
$$
Again, since $|z|>1/3$ then $|1/3z|<1$, and hence 
$$
\frac{1}{3z-1} =\frac{1}{3z(1-1/3z)}=\frac{1}{3z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3z}\right)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3z}\right)^n
$$
Now apply the last two expansions after using partial fractions on your function !

**Spoiler Solution**

**Partial Fractions**

> It is easily seen that the partial fraction decomposition of $f(z)$ is $ f(z)=\frac{1}{3z-1}-\frac{1}{z-1}+1$.

**Laurent Series**

> Hence by the previous expansions $ f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3z}\right)^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n +1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3z}\right)^n + 2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n $.

**Usual Lauren Series form**

> Then in the typical Laurent series expansion form we have that $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n z^n$, where $a_n=3^n$ for $n\leq -1$, $a_0=2$ and $a_n=1$ for $n\geq 1$

Comment: @LukaToni I just added a spoiler solution in case the Hint was not enough, hope it helps!